# Не исчезает счетчик количества сообщений

Tags: php

Знатоки, помогите, пожалуйста, застрял.
По порядку:
1. по нику с сессии получаю автора последнего сообщения.
2. получаю количество сообщений у которых флаг (status_read) = 1
3. условия, по которым в зависимости кто автор сообщения, будет отображаться счетчик или нет.
Так вот на 3 пункте застрял окончательно. условия строил по разному, но в итоге получается либо полная ахинея, либо счетчик так и отображается даже если флаг = 0.
Для полной картины посмотрите скрины.
Буду благодарен за ваши подсказки и возможные варианты решения.
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

[![

```js
<?php 
session_start();
require_once 'connection/db_connect.php'; 
$sess_nick = $_SESSION['nick'];
$stmt = $pdo->prepare("SELECT * FROM dialog WHERE member_nick_from = :member_nick_from OR member_nick_to = :member_nick_to");
$stmt->bindParam(':member_nick_from', $sess_nick, PDO::PARAM_STR);
$stmt->bindParam(':member_nick_to', $sess_nick, PDO::PARAM_STR);
$stmt->execute();
while ($result = $stmt->fetch()) {
 $GLOBALS['autor'] = $result['autor'];
}
$stmt = $pdo->query("SELECT COUNT(*) FROM dialog WHERE member_nick_from = '$sess_nick' OR member_nick_to = '$sess_nick' AND status_read = '1'");
while ($result = $stmt->fetch(PDO::FETCH_NUM)) 
{
 $GLOBALS['res'] = $result[0];
}
?>
```

```js
<?php 
  if ($res > 0) {
   if ($autor == $sess_nick) {
    echo '<a href="dialog">почта</a>';
   }
   if ($autor != $sess_nick) {
    echo '<a href="dialog">почта</a> <span style="color: blue;">(' . $res .')</span>';
   }
  }
  if ($res == 0) {
    echo '<a href="dialog">почта</a>';
  }
?>
```

][2](https://i.stack.imgur.com/cbhnB.png)][2](https://i.stack.imgur.com/cbhnB.png)

Comment: пишите $GLOBALS['autor'] - именно так потом в коде и используйте. А лучше без глобальных переменных.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
$stmt = $pdo->query("SELECT COUNT(*) FROM dialog WHERE status_read = '1' AND (member_nick_from = :member_nick_from_count OR member_nick_to = :member_nick_to_count)");
$stmt->bindParam(':member_nick_from_count', $sess_nick, PDO::PARAM_STR);
$stmt->bindParam(':member_nick_to_count', $sess_nick, PDO::PARAM_STR);
$stmt->execute();
while ($result = $stmt->fetch(PDO::FETCH_NUM))..... и далее свой код
```

1. Параметры биндите через уникальные ключи
2. Не забывайте про ->execute();
3. Используйте () для логического отделения (A or B) and C во время PREPARE

Это должно решить проблему синтаксиса вашего кода.

Так же, насколько я понимаю есть логическая ошибка в самой структуре кода. Речь идет о проверке входящей почты судя по скрину. Следовательно нужно проверять только по member_nick_to, иначе будут считаться также сообщения которые отправил сам автор, но получатель ещё не открыл.

Обратите на это внимание.

Те итоговым решением должно быть:

```
$stmt = $pdo->query("SELECT COUNT(*) FROM dialog WHERE status_read = '1' AND member_nick_to = :member_nick_to_count");
$stmt->bindParam(':member_nick_to_count', $sess_nick, PDO::PARAM_STR);
$stmt->execute();
while ($result = $stmt->fetch(PDO::FETCH_NUM))..... и далее свой код
```

Comment: дело в том, что member_nick_to и  member_nick_from записываются только один раз и больше не меняются. меняется только autor. если в query вставлять бинды, то на выходе получается fatal error. и да, вы правы, при отправке ответа снова привет счетчик. как только сообщение прочитано, то счетчик исчезает

Comment: Используйте уникальные названия для разных PDO сущностей. Одна `$get_author_name = $pdo->query`, другая `$get_messages_count = $pdo->query` и т.д. и в каждом из них используйте уникальные переменные `:variable_name`, 

Тогда проблем не будет. Если меняется author - получайте список где to - логин из сессии, а athor - не равно логину из сессии. 

Получилось объяснить понятно или написать код?

Comment: По статусам вам надо сделать так, чтобы в том месте где status становится 0, он менялся на 0 с проверкой autor. Т.е. только тогда, когда его читает получатель, а не отправитель.

Comment: Дополните сообщение тем кодом где сейчас стирается status и меняется author. Я завтра проснусь - напишу вам с объяснением что, как и для чего.

Comment: в этом случае как не крути, но придется делать то, что мне не хотелось. поправить бд - изменить autor на from_autor, добавить to_autor и переписать всю логику. спасибо за советы - учту.

Comment: Не обязательно.

Comment: после плясок с клавиатурой все сделано и все работает. но интерес берет верх) если у вас есть желание, то я, с удовольствием, посмотрел бы на ваш вариант решения

Comment: Не, если нашел решение которое тебя устраивает - время тратить не буду. Мои советы пригодились?

Comment: Да, некоторыми воспользовался и принял т.с. на вооружение. Благодарю!

Comment: Отлично, успехов!